# How to add to a json file in python

Tags: python, json

I can read the json file and set the information I need to the variables. I have accounts, and I need to be able to add an account to it, this is the code I have so far:

```
import json

user = raw_input("User: ")

with open('text.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

code =  data["users"][user]["pass"]
display = data["users"][user]["display"]

print "Password: " + code
print "Display Name - " + display
```

This works fine to read the file, here is the expected format of the output json file:

```
{
  "users":{
    "User1": {
      "display": "User1",
      "pass": "EzPass123"
    },
    "Richard": {
      "display": "Attack69",
      "pass": "Smith"
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone show me how to add another account to the accounts already existing in the dictionary?

Comment: give an example how your result is supposed to look like

Comment: I did in the json file, it is suppose to look like that

Comment: So? Use the dictionary as you normally would then dump after modification.

Comment: I am not familiar with the json lingo, the code I have is from another question, i just modified it. Can you explain in a little more detail please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution covering the fixes discussed in the other answer:

```
#!python2
import json

# here you read your new user and his password
user = raw_input("User: ")
display = raw_input("Display name: ")
pwd = raw_input("Pass: ")

with open('text.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
    data['users'][user] = {'display':display,'pass':pwd}

with open('text.json','w') as data_file:
    json.dump(data, data_file, indent=4)
```

Output:

```
User: markt
Display name: Mark
Pass: 123
```

Result:

```
{
    "users": {
        "markt": {
            "display": "Mark",
            "pass": "123"
        },
        "Richard": {
            "display": "Attack69",
            "pass": "Smith"
        },
        "User1": {
            "display": "User1",
            "pass": "EzPass123"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, Im making it where it users the username , password = data["users"][user]["pass"]

Comment: when making a new account, i check if there is an account with the name they enter, and if they enter a name not in the database, it breaks, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: is there a way i can set all the names to a variable, example here

Comment: @RichardSmith, you should ask a new question showing the additional code checking for an existing user.

Comment: `data['users'].keys()` will give you the names list.

Comment: thank you, if I have another question I will do so. is there a way to notify you personaly if I do make one?

Comment: A comment with an @ reference will notify me, but it isn't encouraged.  Just ask and let the user base answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
import json

# here you read your new user and his password
user = raw_input("User: ")
display = raw_input("Display name: ")
pwd = raw_input("Pass: ")

with open('text.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
    # update the data dictionary then re-dump it in the file
    data['users'].update({
        user: {
            'display': display,
            'pass': pwd
        }
    })

with open('text.json', 'w') as data_file:
    json.dumps(data, data_file, indent=4)
```

Comment: that replaces user1 witht that information, I need to add a new user

Comment: whops, typoed, updating now

Comment: that doesn't add another account for some reason, but I have no errors

Comment: `json.dump`, not `json.dumps`.  Probably need to rewind the file too if using the same open instance for reading and writing.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "add.py", line 17, in <module>
    json.dump(data, data_file)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 190, in dump
    fp.write(chunk)

Comment: `data_file.seek(0)`.  Also open with `r+` not `rw`.

Comment: where do i insert the data_file.seek(0)

Comment: Actually...should just open for reading, then open for writing.  File won't truncate properly otherwise.

Comment: Is it suppose to change the format? it is all like one line now

Comment: There is an `indent` parameter that can be provided.  I added an answer with all the fixes.

Comment: Sorry, replied to this while on the train then lost connectivity. Yes, should have not rushed it. Will update the answer's code just to avoid providing users with a broken alternative, by no means I seek upvotes.